tkinter set a different color for the tick and text in a checkbox
I'm trying to use checkboxes in tkinter. My GUI has a dark theme so I'd like to use white text on a dark background. Unfortunately if I do this by setting fg="white" bg="black" then I get a black background except for the box where the tick appears which remains white. This means that the tick is white on white background and therfore invisible.
Is there some way to either change the background of the box where the tick appears or, preferably, set the color of the tick mark independent of the rest of the text i.e. so I could have the check itself be a black tick on a white background while the rest of the widget consists of white text on a black background.
To illustrate the issue:
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
var = tk.BooleanVar()
checkbutton = tk.Checkbutton(root, text="example", variable=var, bg="black", fg="white")
checkbutton.grid()
tk.mainloop()


import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.configure(bg="black")  # Set root background to black

var = tk.BooleanVar()
checkbutton = tk.Checkbutton(
    root,
    text="example",
    variable=var,
    fg="white",
    bg="black",
    activeforeground="white",
    activebackground="black",
    selectcolor="gray",  # Background color for the "checked" state
    indicatoron=False
)
checkbutton.grid(padx=20, pady=20)

root.mainloop()


It is better to provide some explanation to make the answer better.

This works in that it differentiates between the checked and unchecked states but isn't what I asked for (a way to set the text and the checkmark to be different colors or a way to change the background of box in which the checkmark sits) and furthermore I don't think it would be particularly clear to the user which state is "on" and which is "off"
